# Elasticsearch should with must_not - non-nested

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

New to Elasticsearch and working on a legacy model that I'm hesitant to change. I have date field that we won't input if it the value is `null` (I think because of the way ES handles `0000-00-00`). I want to be able to query the data that either has a specific date OR where the field doesn't exist. Here is what I have:

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "AccountID": "xxxx"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "LocationID": "xxxx"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "CloseDate": {
                                    "gte": "2020-11-01",
                                    "lte": "2020-12-02"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "CloseDate"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I get and error of `[should] query malformed, no start_object after query name` when trying this though. Is there an alternative syntax or is something really malformed?

Comment: Also, please note this is elasticsearch 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `must` clause can have multiple queries within `[]`. Note that `should` is also a clause of `bool` query and not a query in itself. Therefore it should be inside `bool`.

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "AccountID": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "LocationID": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {            <------------- Note this
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "CloseDate": {
                    "gte": "2020-11-01",
                    "lte": "2020-12-02"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "CloseDate"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errror clearly indicates that your query is not correctly formed. You are missing a `]` bracket.  Try out this query:

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "AccountID": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "LocationID": "xxxx"
          }
        }
      ],                                   <-- note this
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "CloseDate": {
              "gte": "2020-11-01",
              "lte": "2020-12-02"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "CloseDate"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tyler Christian did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: I can't find where I'm missing a bracket. VScode Confirms there are no json errors. Not sure what you are seeing.

Comment: @TylerChristian when you run the same query as that given in your question, you will get the error `[should] query malformed, no start_object after query name`

Comment: right but it wasn't a missing bracket. Its valid JSON. I had a step in code that does `JSON.stringify` it would have failed there first. But thank you for taking time to look at it.

Comment: @TylerChristian Since I was not aware of your use case, so I considered that you want to have a `must` clause and `should` clause separately. That is why I added a `]` at the end of the `must` clause :)